# Spring - database not updated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, session

I'm developing a web application in Spring Framework in Java. I have some trouble with my Postgres database. I try to add a record in the User table in db. The data is collected from the registration form fields. It's saved well, wrapped in a User objects, and all looks fine. Except for the fact, that I don't see any new rows in my DB when I browse it with pgAdmin III. Here is my adding logic:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
   user.setEnabled(true);
   user.setPosts(0);
   System.out.println(user.getId());

   ArrayList <User> list =  (ArrayList<User>) userService.listUser();
   System.out.println(list.size());

   //if (user.getId()==0)
   userService.addUser(user);
//       else
//         userService.editUser(user);

   return "redirect:register.html";
}
```

I do it by invoking a method defined in userService, which calls a method in my userDAO implementation class:

```
public void addUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);        
}
```

What is curious, though, is that when I check the size of my user list, by calling another userDAO method:

```
public List<User> listUser() {

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User order by _id").list();
}
```

the result is non-zero, and increases every time I add a user. Which means, that the data has to be stored somewhere, just I don't know where. The Hibernate access is defined in spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <!--Don't add suffix or prefix like you do with .jsp files -->
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?characterEncoding=utf-8" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="postgres" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">spring3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm pretty sure, too, that the username, password and schema are correct here. Also data displayed correctly in data source explorer of STS. Any ideas? I don't really know where else to look for.

UPDATE:
My class that does transactions has the appropriate annotation, but it's still not working:

The interface:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)  
public interface UserService {

    public void addUser(User user);
    public void editUser(User user);
    public List<User> listUser();
    public void removeUser (int id);
    public User getUser(int id);

}
```

and its implementation:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
UserDAO userDAO;

@Transactional
public void addUser(User user) {
    userDAO.addUser(user);
}

@Transactional
public void editUser(User user) {
    userDAO.editUser(user);
}

@Transactional
public List<User> listUser() {

    return userDAO.listUser();
}

@Transactional
public void removeUser(int id) {
    userDAO.removeUser(id);
}

@Transactional
public User getUser(int id) {
    return userDAO.getUser(id);
}

}
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct database when looking at the records. If you can see them in the browser in STS the records are saved. So I suspect you are looking in the wrong location when using pgAdmin.

Comment: Try looking on your database with the command line, in order to be totally sure the data has not been saved like M. Deinum said. Still I'm surprised that you don't flush the session or use the @Transactional notation on your Controler

Comment: It's still on an early stage, right now I'm just checking if the connection works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an issue because you didn't flush your session.

If you don't flush your session the data will be persisted in the hibernate session, but not in a final state ie not in the database.

Since you are using Spring just put the @Transactional annotation on your controller method should be enough : it handles the session, the commit and flush automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's clear from your inputs that you didn't configure to commit the transaction manually or automatically. You can do it in following ways.

> Manual settings:

In your DAO class, Initialize the transaction and do commit manually.

```
public void addUser(User user) {
  try{
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    trans.commit();
   }catch(Exception e){
     trans.rollback();
   }
}
```

> Autocommit using spring `@Transactional` annotation:

Since you are using Spring along with Hibernate, you need not want to manually do all these commit, rollback stuff like I mentioned above (That is one way of doing, but it's not a good practice when using along with spring). Spring does this for you. You have already configured transaction management in your spring configuration xml. Now just use `@Transactional` annotation on your controller or service methods where you call the DAO class for db operations.

```
@Transactional
public xx xx(){ //Your userService method that calls DAO method
..
}
```

Note: The `@Transactional` annotation should be of spring's (`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`). Do not use `javax.transaction` here.

Comment: I did add those annotations. And I'm certain I'm using the same connection in pgAdmin and DataSourceExplorer of STS, because I added a test table in pgAdmin, and it was updated in DataSourceExplorer. I posted the changes in my post. Still not working though.